# What the closed under taking all possible linear combinations mean for subspace on linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I learn from the lecture sheet about ‘subspace’. I am struggle with what can be satisfy as a subspace in linear algebra?

I know there are two, first is should contain zero constant or zero vector. But do not familiar with the second property of the subspace, is it should be satisfy with both addition closed and multiplication closed for a linear combination? Then it could be say as a subspace.
Or only need to satisfy with one of them (addition closed and multiplication closed), then it can be a subspace?

Lots if thanks!

Comment: What is the definition mentioned in the lecture sheet?

Comment: It must be closed by both operations.

Answer (score 2):

A subspace $V$ must satisfy the following properties. Firstly, as you said, it must contain the 0 vector. The second property is that for all scalars $a$ and vectors $v \in V$, then $av \in V.$ This means that if you take any vector in the space $V$, all of its multiples must be in $V$.

The last property it satisfies is that if $v, w \in V$, then $v+w \in V$. This means that if you take any two vectors and add them, then they are also in $V$.

Intuitively, a subspace represents a *linear* subset of the whole space. For example, suppose that your total vector space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is the two dimensional plane. Then, a subspace could be a line passing through the origin. If your total vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3,$ then maybe a subspace could be any plane passing through the origin. A plane passing through the origin is a subspace because it contains the 0 vector (the origin), and if you take any vectors on the plane and either multiply them by a scalar or add them, then the resulting vector is still on the plane, so it is closed under multiplication by a scalar and by adding vectors in the plane (i.e., under *linear* combinations).

Another way to view this is that if $a$ is a scalar and $v,w \in V,$ then $av + w \in V$ (because $av \in V$ by the first property, and then $av + w \in V$ by the second property). So the idea is that you can take *linear* combinations of vectors and they will still remain in the subspace. In the example above with the plane, you can think of a plane as just a generalization of a straight line, so it is a *linear* space. When you think of subspace, you should generally think of something that is linear, so that when you add vectors in the subspace, you're going to get another vector that is still contained in the space.